# Why does Google Spreadsheet not connect to Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

For example, if I follow this simple 5 minute tutorial provided by google: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs, translate.gs and sidebar.html will not connect to the Google Spreadsheet that I created. In this tutorial, the following step is not working for me:

1. Switch back to your document and reload the page.
2. **After a few seconds**, a Translate Quickstart sub-menu will appear under the Add-ons menu. (If you chose a different name for your script, that name will appear instead.) Click Add-ons > Translate Quickstart > Start."

The translate Quickstart sub-menu is not appearing. From what I understand, File > 'Save all' should update my translate.gs and sidebar.html automatically.

No matter how many new google spreadsheets I make with corresponding .gs files, the .gs file functions are not found by it's corresponding spreadsheet.

I have also tried resetting my cache after reading some suggestions online.

EDIT: I was asked for permission when initially running this function through the Script Editor. I granted it permissions and ran the function and received the correct log which can be seen in this image [image]

Any insight on this strange behavior would be great! Thanks!

Edit: This time when I am asked for permissions, I am unable to give permission to my own app despite this all being done through my account [image]

Comment: The functions run correctly in the script editor and I am also receiving the correct log results if I click *View > Logs* on a function with Logger.log('test');

Comment: Initially it did ask for permissions which I granted. I've updated the question for you with an image of the logs

Comment: Go to the advanced mode and you will be able to authorize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 5 minute Quickstart tutorial you linked is for Google docs. It fails because there is no `DocumentApp` but only `SpreadsheetApp` For Google sheets quick start, Go here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/macros

Comment: Yup. You are right. Thank you for being patient with me

Comment: The exact same error occurs when going through this tutorial too. Reloading the spreadsheet does not add the script after saving it in the script editor. I think I will ask a new question for this.